# Conditional with promise in Ramda

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, promise, ramda.js

How can I use `R.cond` with promises ?

Something like this ..

```js
const fetchBin = (url) => fetch(`https://httpbin.org${url}`).then((response) => {
    var contentType = response.headers.get("content-type");
    if(contentType && contentType.includes("application/json")) {
      return response.json();
    }
    throw new TypeError("Oops, we haven't got JSON!");
})

const testStatus = (status) => fetchBin(`/status/${status}`);

const isOk = R.propEq('statusCode', 200);
const testCond = R.cond([
    [ R.pipeP(testStatus, isOk), (resp) => console.log('The resp is ', resp) ],
    [ R.T, (code) => console.log('The resp is NOT ok', code) ]
])

testCond(404)
// R.pipeP(testStatus, isOk)(404)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.24.1/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I think you should have `testCond` part inside a `then` of `testStatus`, because according to the Ramda docs the predicate is supposed to be a pure function in `cond`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you are after, by composing it with `testStatus` you should be able to get the `response` object and do the conditional branching.

```js
const fetchBin = (url) => fetch(`https://httpbin.org${url}`).then((response) => {
    var contentType = response.headers.get("content-type");
    if(contentType && contentType.includes("application/json")) {
      return response.json();
    }
    throw new TypeError("Oops, we haven't got JSON!");
})

const testStatus = (status) => fetchBin(`/status/${status}`);

const isOk = R.propEq('statusCode', 200);
const testCond = R.pipeP(testStatus, R.cond([
  [isOk, resp => console.log('The resp is OK :' + resp.statusCode)],
  [R.T, resp => console.log('The resp is NOT OK :' + resp.statusCode)]
]));

testCond(404)
// R.pipeP(testStatus, isOk)(404)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.24.1/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hi @MinusFour,  I tried your suggestion but didn't work.  

`R.pipeP(testStatus, /* If the promise is not resolved (catch in this case) the condition are not executed */)`

You can check [here](https://runkit.com/ridermansb/ramda-promises)

Comment: That's going to be somewhat of a problem if you depend on the catch clause, you'll have to fulfill the promise even if it rejects. I was under the impression that even for 400 status codes you were returning a JSON answer with a 400 status code property.

Answer (score 2):

**a fresh perspective**

> it's good to remind ourselves that we should be the ones bending our programming languages, not the other way around

It seems to me like you're beating down the wrong path. `fetchBin` is a straw man of the guy we're really looking for. We need a function that takes a URL and returns the parsed JSON response; let's call this man, `fetchJSON`

From there, we implement `fetchBin` using `fetchJSON` – it doesn't matter whether the resource returns a `404` status or a `200` status with the wrong content type (see the XML example below) - either way, the promise will be correctly routed to the error handler (`console.error` below; alternatively `.then(console.log).catch(console.error)`) – the point here, in case I'm not being clear, is that `fetchBin` should not be concerned with details like what the HTTP status code is or what the Content-Type header of the response might be – just let it ask for the parsed JSON, and stop worrying about the rest

My reason for sharing this is to help you avoid getting stuck in a particular way of thinking. `R.cond` is a pretty *bad* form, if we're being perfectly honest – it forces you to adjust the semantics of your program's fork by caging it in an array and creating thunks to hold conditional branches which maybe never be used by your program; *true* laziness is only available in strictly-evaluated JavaScript using `if/else` or `?:`; without them you're still doing unnecessary work

Once we unbind ourselves from a rigid form like `R.cond`, things fit together quite naturally – heck, we didn't even end up needing `R.pipe`, or `R.pipeP`, or `R` at all...

```js
const fetchJSON = url =>
  fetch (url)
    .then (responseOK)
    .then (parseJSON)

const responseOK = (response) =>
  {
    if (response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300)
      return response
    else
      throw Object.assign (Error (response.statusText), { response })
  }

const parseJSON = response =>
  response.json ()
    
const fetchBin = (url) =>
  fetchJSON ('https://httpbin.org' + url)

fetchBin ('/anything?a=b') .then (console.log, console.error)
// all things good !
// => { args: {a: 'b'}, data: '' ... }

fetchBin ('/status/404') .then (console.log, console.error)
// non-200 status goes to error handler
// => { Error: NOT FOUND ..., response }

fetchBin ('/xml') .then (console.log, console.error)
// bad JSON goes to error handler
// => SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
```

---

Ok so we didn't need `R` there, but this answer doesn't mean to imply that as a general rule-of-thumb. Ramda is a great tool and can teach you a lot about functional programming – just remember to take a step back sometimes and evaluate whether your program can be expressed in a way *you* want, rather than worrying about what the language (or library, or function; `R.cond`) wants